# Printing names in ListView Android using json and AsyncTask

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

i have a json file from a database which looks like this

{"students":[{"id":"1","name":"sami"},{"id":"2","name":"subhi"},{"id":"3","name":"james"}]}

and i used two java classes in my android application but there is no thing show.
the code :

Main activity class:

```
package com.subhi.json1;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<String> studentlist;
    ListView x1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        x1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list1);

        DownloadClass x1=new DownloadClass(this);
        x1.execute("http://192.168.1.102/json1/index.php");
    }

    public void setlist(ArrayList<String> list ){

        studentlist=list;

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,studentlist);
        x1.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Download Class :

```
package com.subhi.json1;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by subhi on 12/19/2015.
 */
public class DownloadClass  extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

    MainActivity activity;
    Context context;

    public DownloadClass (MainActivity activity){

        this.activity=activity;
        this.context=activity.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        ArrayList<String> studentlist=new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            JSONArray students=new JSONArray(s);
            for (int i=0;i<students.length();i++)
            {

                JSONObject student= students.getJSONObject(i);
                int id=student.getInt("id");
                String studentname=student.getString("name");

                studentlist.add(" id "+id+" name "+studentname);
            }
            activity.setlist(studentlist);

        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection=null;
        InputStream inputStream=null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream content=null;
        try {

            URL url=new URL(params[0]);


            connection= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            if(connection.getResponseCode()!=HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            {
                Log.d("Server Erppr", connection.getResponseMessage());
                return "Error in Connection to server|";



            }

            Log.d("Connection Error",connection.getResponseMessage());
            inputStream=connection.getInputStream();
            content=new ByteArrayOutputStream();



            byte [] buff=new byte[2048];

            long total=0;
            int count=0;

            while ((count=inputStream.read(buff))!=-1)
            {

                content.write(buff,0,count);
                total=total+count;

            }






        }
        catch (Exception ex){

            ex.printStackTrace();

        }

        finally {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
                connection.disconnect();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


        return new String(content.toByteArray());
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a jsonException in the logs ?

Comment: no , the log cat doesn't show any thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone, it seems that my JSON format wasn't well. so i had change it to be like this and it works.

```
[{"id":"1","name":"sami"},{"id":"2","name":"subhi"},{"id":"3","name":"james"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

can you change your `int id=student.getInt("id");` to `String id=student.getString("id");` and see if that helps ?

Comment: i had done that , but it does not help, it keeps the same, no thing to print and the log cat does not show anything

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
JSONObject jsonObjectResult = new JSONObject(s);

JSONArray students = jsonObjectResult.getJSONArray("students");

for (int i=0; i<students.length(); i++){

    JSONObject student = (JSONObject) students.get(i);

    int id = student.getInt("id");
    //Remember, if id is a text: student.getString("id")

    String studentname = student.getString("name");

    studentlist.add(" id " + id + " name " + studentname);
}
```

Good luck!